# Custom child page permalink

Tags: permalinks, filters, url-rewriting, child-pages

I'm trying to customize the permalink of some child pages.

I have this structure:
`example.com/story/story-name-slug/chapter-slug/page-slug`

And I'm trying to transforming that structure into this:
`example.com/section/page-slug`

But also I want to keep the other links active, so in the end I should have the following:
`example.com/story` -> archive of all story;

`example.com/story/story-name-slug` -> list of all chapters;

`example.com/section/page-slug` -> page with customized url.

Keep in mind that `example.com/story/story-name-slug/chapter-slug` is not a page that can be visited by users. It's only used to archive the hierarchical relation between pages.

At the moment I got the url structure working with the following code in functions.php:

```
add_filter('page_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('page_type_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);

function custom_permalink($permalink, $post_id) {

    $post = get_post($post_id);

    $post_name = $post->post_name;

    $id_chapter = $post->post_parent;
    $id_story = wp_get_post_parent_id($id_chapter);
    $id_stories = wp_get_post_parent_id($id_story);

    if ($id_chapter !== 0 && $id_story !== 0 && $id_stories ) {
        // the static base url is just for testing
        $permalink = 'example.com/section/' . $post_name ;
    } else {
        $permalink = $permalink;
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```

This works but not as it shoudl, I get the right URLs on the right pages but when I visit those pages I get a 404 Error not found.

After some digging in the sql queris that get executed I think that the problem is that WP is selecting `wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment'` instead of `wp_posts.post_type = 'page'`.

I think that a rewrite rule is needed somewhere to specify in the sql query what to select, but this goes over my current capabilities.

If it's needed I can provide all the queries that get executed on the page with and without the filter that I added.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand your current and intended URL structures... What I'm interpreting is that your pages are currently presented under the URL base `/story`. Then "stories" "chapters" and "pages" are all really just Page post-types nested under each other - as far as WordPress is concerned they're all the same type of content, and subject to the same categories and taxonomies. But you're trying to create a URL structure which entirely disregards the hierarchy of the pages, is this correct?

Comment: But you say "`example.com/story/story-name-slug/chapter-slug` is not a page that can be visited by users. It's only used to archive the hierarchical relation between pages."... Does this mean that it's still a Page post-type which you do not intend for users to visit directly, or is this URL some product of a custom taxonomy you've created? While this question may be able to be solved with a simple rewrite rule, I suspect it might be better to re-organize your content into custom posts and taxonomies, if I'm understanding the situation correctly.

Comment: Hello @bosco, thanks for your answer. I've explained everything better, with also a simple drawing, in this image: https://imgur.com/a/QsoPHml

Comment: I'll add that no taxonomies or categories are in use. Only parent-child relationships are used..